# batch script to compare list files

Tags: batch-file

I have a list in text file

```
abc
abc_1
abc_2
cbd
cbd_1
cbd_2
```

And theres alot more to the lines as well like dates and other randomness.  What I want to do is for a script to like for each file, but when it looks for a file it will compare to another text for for that same file name.  And then if it doesn't find it, write it to that text and continue with a full search.  The part of the script I am stuck on...says do was unexpected at this time.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\conflicts\vids.txt) DO for /f "tokens=1 delim=_" %%i ("%%a") do (
find %%i in (C:\conflicts\exists.txt) do (
if exist goto :end
echo %%i >> C:\conflicts\exists.txt
) else if exist \\networklocation\%%i.mpg (
ECHO FOUND %%i IN NETWORKLOCATION >> C:\conflicts\vids1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... DO for /f "tokens=1 delim=_" %%i ("%%a") do
```

missing 'IN' probably generating your 'unexpected do'

```
... if exist goto :end
```

If exist **what** goto end?

`if exist` looks for a match. This would look for a file named 'goto' and if found would execute `:end'

You've only posted a partial statement - there are missing round-brackets and who-knows-what else.

Please give examples to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve. Your torrent of pronouns is unfortunately, indecipherable.

Answer (score 0):

try this out .. maybe it does what you want ..

for /f "tokens=*" %%c in (your text file here) do (

cd\

for / r %%f in (*) do (

if %%c==%%~nf echo file name match found %%f

pause

)

)

after the if statement you can put any command you wish depending on what you wanna do with the results ....
hope this helps out ..